# Vuecli installation

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I am trying to install vue cli on my ubuntu os.....and i can t because of some errors....and i have npm version 6.13.4 ....idk why it says that i have 2.6.11...i have already tried to delete cache and node modules and npm install again....but it doesn t work....any help, pls?

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
/usr/local/bin/vue -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/2575/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

2020/01/02 01:50:38.033096 cmd_run.go:884: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/nonexistent/snap/node/2575": mkdir /nonexistent: permission denied
cannot create user data directory: /nonexistent/snap/node/2575: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-01T23_50_41_447Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

> i have npm version 6.13.4 ....idk why it says that i have 2.6.11

This makes me a little nervous.  You should be able to run `which npm` to figure out *where* the 2.6.11 version is coming from. But with that said it may not be worth your time to investigate.

At the risk of sending you down a rabbit hole I would suggest `Node Version Manager`(NVM): https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. Pretty basic, NVM will let you set a definitive version of Node and NPM.  To get started just:

1. Copy and run this (from the readme) curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
2. Run `nvm install stable`.  That should download and install the latest stable version of Node and NPM.
3. Probably safe to run `npm cache clean` to get to a cleaner slate.

From there I'd re-try your cli install: `npm install -g @vue/cli` following the steps here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html